# Is there any way I could open up 2 tabs with compared files in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, compare, cvs

I am trying to compare a file with its history in cvs, while I’m doing it with 2 files in one time, the first compared file gets removed. sound like eclipse don't like 2 compared files open together.  
 the only way I can compare 2 different files in one time is if I edit something in the file... 
I’m using 'eclipse indigo'.

Comment: I did not understand your question.

Comment: @Adarsh i know its a bit  hard to explain, try to compare a file in eclipse, it will open a new file with your files you selected, then while the compared file is open try to compare a different file, you'll see that the first compared files will close automatically... Try it out and tell me if you don't get it. Tnx!

Comment: Nope. every compare of 2 files opens in a new tab..and the previous compare still stays

Comment: @Adarsh are you using indigo? even without editing in the first compare tab? I did it at my workmates eclipse and the previous compare tab closed as well.

Comment: No, I am using Juno. But even when I used indigo, I could do it.

Comment: @Adarsh Don't know, just tried it in the new 'eclipse kepler' and i have the same problem. i cant have 2 compare tabs open in one time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30856/discussion-between-elye-m-and-adarsh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window >> Prefereces >> Team >>  and check off  `Reuse open compare editors when opening comparisons`